# Connecting two draggeable, sortable objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have two elements that are connected one is a sidebar element and the other is a chart or object that represents the data. If the sidebar is reordered then the corresponding, connected object should be reordered with the sidebar element. That is the problem. Both objects will move together but will not resort or snap into place. They will just go back to their original position. I wan to be able to reorder the sidebar and the corresponding chart or object to be reordered on the page in the correct position. I will provide the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "#sortable" )
.sortable({ handle: ".handle", placeholder: "ui-state-highlight", helper: 'clone'  })   
.find("li")  
.prepend("<div class='handle'><p >&#9776</p></div>" )    
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#sortable').click(function() {
    var address = $('#sortable').val();      
});
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});    
$(document).on('click')       
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.move-up').click(function(){
    if ($(this).prev()) 
        $(this).parent().insertBefore($(this).parent().prev());
});
$('.move-down').click(function(){
    if ($(this).next())
        $(this).parent().insertAfter($(this).parent().next());
});
});
$(document).ready(function() {
// function to get matching groups (change '.group' and /group.../ inside the match to whatever class you want to use
var getAll = function(t) {
    return $('.group' + t.helper.attr('class').match(/group([0-9]+)/)[1]).not(t);
};
// add drag functionality
$(".dragme").draggable({
    snap: true,
    revert: true,
    containment: "#containment-wrapper",
    axis:"y", 
    revertDuration: 10,
});

<input class="input btn-info" id='toggle' name='toggle' type="button" value="<">
<div id="draggable">
<ul  id="sortable">  

<div class="dragme group1"><li  id="item-1" class="ui-state-default">Executive Summary
    <button class="delete btn-danger" ><p class="icon-remove"></p></button>
    <button class="move-up btn-info"><p class="icon-chevron-up"></p></button><br />
    <button class="move-down btn-info"><p class="icon-chevron-down"></p></button>

</li></div> 
<div class="dragme group2"><li  id="item-2" class="ui-state-default">Company     Performance<button class="delete btn-danger"><p class="icon-remove"></p></button>
    <button class="move-up btn-info"><p class="icon-chevron-up"></p></button> <br />
    <button class="move-down btn-info"><p class="icon-chevron-down"></p></button>
</li></div>


     <div class="span10" id="draggable" style="float: right; width: 75%;">
<div class="row-fluid" ><div class="dragme group1">
<div class="span3"><div class="box style2"><span class="number">115,925</span><p>Total   Impressions</p></div></div>
<div class="span3"><div class="box style2"><span class="number">1,100</span><p>Total Clicks</p></div></div>
<div class="span3"><div class="box style2"><span class="number">102</span><p>Total Leads</p></div></div>
<div class="span3"><div class="box style2"><span class="number">7.2%</span><p>Overall  Conversions</p></div></div>
</div></div>


 <div class="dragme group2"><div class="tab-content" id="white-bg">
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="impressions">                                                      
                            <div id="chart_div" style=" width: 900px; height: 400px;">   </div>
                        </div>
                   </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: really not sure what you are asking...create a demo in jsfiddle.net that outlines issue